# Fastest way to show that $\frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 1}$ is decreasing for functions that are $x \geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Fastest way to show that $ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 1}$ is decreasing for functions that are $x \geq 0$

The only current way I know is derivative test which is proved which seems to be the longest way I think. I'm just wondering if there is a easier way out there.

Comment: Do you see another way of writing  the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Write $y^2=e^x, y\ge0$  to find $$g(y)=\dfrac{y^2}{(y^2+1)^2}=\dfrac1{\left(y-\dfrac1y\right)^2+2}=\cdots$$

As $x\ge0, y^2=e^x\ge1\implies y\ge1$

Now, $a-\dfrac1a$ will be $>b-\dfrac1b\iff\dfrac{(a-b)(ab+1)}{ab}>0\iff a-b>0$ for $ab>0$

Answer (score 2):

We note that we can rewrite the function as 
$$f(x) = \frac{1/e^x}{1/e^x}\cdot f(x) = \frac{1}{e^x + 2 + \frac{1}{e^x}}.$$

Now, we just need to confirm that the denominator is increasing on $x\geq 0$ (since the numerator is constant).

Now, instead of having to take the derivative of a fraction, we simply take the derivative of the denominator and note it is 
$$e^x-e^{-x}$$ which is clearly non-negative on $x \geq 0.$

This helps maintain the same solution method that you used (derivative test), but makes the computation much simpler throughout.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
h(x) = \frac{e^x}{(e^x + 1)^2}
$$
We can note that $h(x) = f(g(x))$ where 
$$
g(x) = e^x, \quad f(x) = \frac{x}{(x + 1)^2}
$$
Since $g(x)$ is an increasing function, it suffices to show that $f$ is an decreasing function over the domain $x \geq e^0 = 1$.

Now, note that the function $p(x) = 1/x$ is decreasing over this domain.  It's therefore enough to show that that function $p(f(x))$ is increasing.  But
$$
p(f(x)) = \frac{(x + 1)^2}{x} = x - 2 + \frac 1x = (x + 1/x) - 2
$$
It's pretty easy to show that this function is increasing using derivatives.